# Embed D3 graph into a handlebar template

Tags: javascript, d3.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to embed a d3 graph into a handlebar template but when i am embedding the object registryhelper of handlebar returns [object SVGSVGElement] not as html.

**D3 graph with handlebar registry helper**

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function() {
 svg = d3.select('p').append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
 var rect1 =svg.append("rect").attr("x",0).attr("y",3*h/4).
 attr("width",w).attr("height",rect_1_h).style("fill",rect_1_color);
 return svg;
 });
```

**Handlebar Template**

```
{{#each objects}}
 <tr>
 <td><p>{{#list}}{{/list}}</p></td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Please how did you eventually resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handlebars is displaying the `toString` value of the `svg` object.

Use the `html()` method to get the HTML representation of `svg`, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html

Then use `Handlebars.SafeString` to indicate Handlebars to not escape the HTML, something like this: `return new Handlebars.SafeString(svg.html())`

But before doing that, take account that are some issues in your example:

1. You are using `d3.select` which means, select an element from DOM. Then you are affecting that element in the DOM directly. Is not working like a "function", probably what you want to do is to create the `p` element in memory. Or perhaps you can resolve the problem working with the DOM without creating a Handlebars helper.
2. A small issue: add `var` to svg or you'll be using a global.